# NGINX: Redirect to Non-www address

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, https

I am trying to configure my website with NGINX. I'm a bit out of my depth and have tried all the relevant solutions I could find, so your patience is appreciated :)

I want all http traffic to redirect to https, and connections to my website's www subdomain and to my server ip address (123.123.123.123 for our purposes) should redirect to mywebsite.com. My server configuration is below, and it meets all of these criteria except the www redirect, which gives me an NGINX 404 page. What I don't understand is that the handling of the ip address and the www subdomain seem identical to me - is the problem elsewhere, such as DNS or SSL certificates? Thank you.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/mywebsite

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name www.mywebsite.com mywebsite.com 123.123.123.123 ;
        return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri ;
}
server {
        server_name www.mywebsite.com ;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri ;


}
server {
        server_name 123.123.123.123;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri ;


}
server {
        server_name mywebsite.com ;
        root /var/www/mywebsite ;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html ;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404 ;
        }
        if ($host != mywebsite.com) {
                return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
        } 


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

```
root@localhost:~# certbot certificates
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: mail.mywebsite.com
    Serial Number: ###################################
    Key Type: ECDSA
    Domains: mail.mywebsite.com
    Expiry Date: 2023-12-09 16:27:55+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: mywebsite.com
    Serial Number: ###################################
    Key Type: ECDSA
    Domains: mywebsite.com mail.mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com
    Expiry Date: 2023-12-09 03:09:48+00:00 (VALID: 88 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

For DNS, I have A and AAAA records for mywebsite.com and *.mywebsite.com pointing to my server's ipv4 and ipv6 addresses respectively, as well as an MX record and some TXT records for my mail subdomain.

```
A   mywebsite.com   123.123.123.123 600     
A   *.mywebsite.com 123.123.123.123 600     
AAAA    mywebsite.com   1234:1234::1234:1234:1234:1234  600     
AAAA    *.mywebsite.com 1234:1234::1234:1234:1234:1234  600     
MX  mywebsite.com   mail.mywebsite.com  600 10  
TXT _dmarc.mywebsite.com    v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:dmarc@mywebsite.com; fo=1    600     
TXT mywebsite.com   v=spf1 mx a:mail.mywebsite.com -all 600     
TXT mail._domainkey.mywebsite.com   v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=#####################################   600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(this is mostly comment, but space is limited)

> I want all http traffic to redirect to https,

OK, seems sensible.

> and connections to my website's www subdomain and to my server ip address (123.123.123.123 for our purposes) should redirect to mywebsite.com

Why? I see no benefit to this and it effectively closes the door on any high availability for the service.

Yes, a casual inspection of the config suggests it should do what you think. However why are you using different server blocks to describe [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) and 123.123.123.123 when they implement the same behaviour? (Actually you could implement the behaviour for 3 SSL vhosts in a single server block). Similarly you don't need the separate certificate for mail.mywebsite.com.

A certificate issue is unlikely to result in a 404 error.

DNS seems like the obvious thing to check / conversely you could explicitly override any existing DNS and see the actual HTTP headers using (for example):

```
curl -I -k --resolve \*:443:123.123.123 https://www.example.com
```

Comment: My logic for the ip redirect was simply that I got an nginx 404 instead of my site, and I didn't see any reason not to have it redirect. I am adding my DNS to the above post in more detail.

Comment: Everything *should* redirect to www.mywebsite.com. You've added anonymized data - how did you verify these settings?

Comment: I was hoping for the site to redirect to mywebsite.com instead. Again, only the redirect from www to non-www doesn't work, and that is my main objective. Regarding the anonymized data, I copied my settings verbatim and only changed the domian, ip, and keys. I can add some curl outputs for a better picture of what's going on. Thanks for the help so far, by the way.

Comment: Resolved. I had an additional config file causing the issue. Thank you for the help regardless, and I will keep the point about not redirecting from the ip address in mind.